# ExtJS--How to center align two toolbar buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I have a grid panel with a bottom toolbar:

```
this.bbar = [
      "->",                 
      {
        text:"<font color = white><b>Save</b></font>", itemId:"save", 
      },
      "<-",
      {       
        tooltip:"Back to Home Screen", itemId:"backhome", text:"<b>&lt; back</b>"             
      }
 ];
```

the right arrow -> moves the save button all the way to the right. So I thought adding a left arrow <- would center the two buttons that did not work. Both buttons are pushed to the right and the left arrow can be seen so i dont think "<-" is valid.

Is there another approach i can take to center my two buttons?

thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append `layout` config to your toolbar.

```
layout: {
    pack: 'center',
    type: 'hbox'
}
```

Documentation (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Box-cfg-pack)